# Magento 2 admin grid module redirecting to dashboard

Tags: magento-2.1, module

I have created a custom grid module in magento 2, It created a menu in admin panel, on click of menu, it is redirecting to dashboard and `system.log` has following errors :

```
...
[2017-07-01 04:11:57] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_391fccd54da687afc76a5d6559b714906 and handles default, adminhtml_dashboard_index: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-07-01 04:11:57] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_3cf9ab1b1723bedc1dcd665a812b00335 and handles admin-1column: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-07-01 04:11:57] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-07-01 04:11:57] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-07-01 04:11:57] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2017-07-01 04:11:59] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
...
```

**My menu.xml file is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Company_Custom::manager" title="Grid Manager" module="Company_Custom" sortOrder="10" resource="Company_Custom::manager"/>
        <add id="Company_Custom::add_row" title="Grid Manager" module="Company_Custom" sortOrder="20" parent="Company_Custom::manager" action="company_custom/custom/index" resource="Magento_Backend::content"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**And routes.xml is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="company_custom" frontName="company_custom">
            <module name="Company_Custom" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Why is it redirecting to dashboard?

Comment: May Be check your Xml, in xml You have not configured right controller paths

Comment: Try to put your action as **custom/custom/index** .

Comment: Hi @PranayK, please check my edited question.

Comment: Hi @DineshYadav, I tried that, but not working.

Comment: Your controller might have some problem. Have you tried echo something and exit in your controller ?

Comment: I tried to `echo 'Some'; exit;` but still redirecting to dashboard.

Comment: Did You run the commands di compile and deploy @VinayaMaheshwari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change "**Controllers**" to "**Controller**" then check

**Change:** Company/Custom/**Controller**/Adminhtml/Custom/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Custom\Controller\Adminhtml\Custom;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $_resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context        $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) 
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

/**
 * Grid List page.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Grid List'));

    return $resultPage;
}
```

}